# Text Based UNO with Colors and Bots

Tags: c++, game

This is the first big thing I have tried in c++. I would like to know any improvements that I can make on it. It uses 4 custom header files, 3 of which are general tools.

Also I am on linux and I have no idea how to check how this would work on windows. I know some colors might look different or it might not look as expected so if someone could help me on how to check that.

**UNO.cpp**

This is the file thats compiled to an executable

```
#include "Card.hpp"
#include "MagnTxt.hpp"
#include "GetSS.hpp"

using namespace std;

void Rules();//Prints All Rules
void Begin(Cards arr[]);//Draws 6 Cards For Each Player
void Orderfrom(int si, vector<int>& v);//Orders Indexes from si - l and then 0 - si and stores it in v
void getCardSize();//Asks The Users For Card Length and Cards Width
vector<string> setPlayers(int p, int b);//Creates 2 Vectors using setName appends them and returns it
vector<string> setName(string ty, int n);//Asks The User for n of ty else names all ty 1, ty 2, ..., ty n
void GetStatus(vector<string> n, int si);//Gets Status of All Player starting from si'th Player
void PrintOrder(vector<int> oi, vector<string> pn, int si);//Prints Turn Order using Player Name from pn Starting from si
void PlusN(int n);//Prints + n using MagnTxt.hpp
void ReverseOrder(vector<int>& v, int& p);//Reverses Order And Changes p to New Index After Reverses Order
void SwitchWith(Cards& plt, Cards& plf);//Switches plt's Cards with plf's Cards
void SwitchAll(Cards arr[], vector<int> ord);//Switches All Cards Based On Turn Order Stored in ord
void SpCard(vector<int>& o, int& ind, int& m, string& c, string& ctdp, bool ib);//If A Card Is Special it Changes Accepted Values Based on The Special Card
int PlDraws(Cards& pl, string& c, string ctdp, int& m, int& ind, bool sm, bool ib);//It Makes pl Draw m Cards or Draws Until They Are Able To Play
int O7SpM(Cards arr[], vector<string> pl, vector<int> o, string c, int& i, bool o7, bool ib, int o7i);//Switches Cards if 0 or 7 is Played and o7mode is Enabled
void SafeCin(string msg, string err, int& i, int ll, int ul);//Shows msg accepts value for i, for invalid or out of bounds input it asks again with err shown
void UpdateLengths();//Sets New Card Length and Card Width Based on The Screen Size and lenf and widf
void Clear();//Clears Screen Using cls or clear based on os
void Stopper();//Asks For Any Input Before Clearing The Screen
void WinningMessage(string mssg);//Shows Winning Message Magnified And Colorful using MagnTxt.hpp

ScreenSize ss;
int lenf = 420, widf = 105, Div = 1000, cl, cw, space;//Stores Arbitary lenf, widf to set Card Length, Card Width and Spaces Before Displaying Singlar Card

int main()
{
    bool isBot = false, o7cond = false;//isBot Stores If The Current Player is a Bot, o7cond stores if 07 Mode is Enabled or not
    int nop = 0, nob = 0, mult = 0, ctp, i = 0, o7, acs, cind = 0;
    /*nop stores number of players, nob stores number of bots, mult stores Number of Cards to Draw, ctp stores the index of card to play, i stores the index that loops through order, acs stores all cards size of the current player, cind stores the crrent players index*/
    string lcard = "", ctdp = "";//lcard stores last card and ctdp stores the card to display which has the selected color stored immediately after playing
    vector<int> order;//Stores Turn Order using indexes
    Rules();
    SafeCin("Enter Number of Players: ", "\nNumber of Players Cant be Less than or Equal to 1\n", nop, 1, numeric_limits<int>::max());//gets nop from 1 - max_int
    SafeCin("Enter Number of Bots: ", "\nNumber of Players Cant be Less than or Equal to 0\n", nob, 0, numeric_limits<int>::max());//gets nop from 0 - max_int
    SafeCin("\nActivate 0-7 Mode ?(1 for Yes, Anything Else for No): ", "\nNon-Numerical Values Not Allowed!", o7, numeric_limits<int>::min(), numeric_limits<int>::max());//Allows for any numerical integer value and stores it in o7
    getCardSize();
    vector<string> players = setPlayers(nop, nob);//Stores All Player Names And All Bots Name in players
    Cards PlArr[nop + nob];//Creates Cards Objects for both Players and Bots
    if(o7 == 1 && Cards::count > 1)//Activates o7cond if user entered 1 for o7 and there are more than 1 player
        o7cond = true;
    Orderfrom((rand() % Cards::count), order);//Orders Index from a random number between 0 to Cards::count(which is total number of objects)
    Begin(PlArr);//Draws Cards for All Objects
    Clear();
    cout<<"This Game Will Start with: "<<players[order[0]];//Shows the Player That The Game Will Start With
    while(true)//Infinite Loop
    {
        i -= (i >= Cards::count) ? Cards::count : 0;//Makes i safe, say skip is played at i = 2 and Cards::count = 3, i will become 4 when it needs to be 1, this will make i the desired num as i - Cards::count will be 1
        cind = order[i];//Stores the actual index of the player getting it from order using i
        Stopper();
        UpdateLengths();
        isBot = cind >= nop;//As bots are added after players all indexes greater than equal to nop will be of bots
        PlArr[cind].Sort();//Sorts All Cards Color Wise
        GetStatus(players, cind);
        PrintOrder(order, players, i);
        if(lcard != "")//Prints ctdp if lcard isn't empty i.e ctdp is displayed when a card has been played
        {
            cout<<"\n\nPreviously Played Card: \n";
            Cards::Display(ctdp, cl, cw  + 2, -1, space);
        }
        if(mult != 0)//If mult is not 0 i.e there are n cards to draw(i.e previosly draw 2 or draw 4 has been played)
        {
            cout<<Cards::SetTextColor(ctdp, -1);//Sets a new color based on the color of draw 2 or color choosen for draw 4
            PlusN(mult);
            cout<<Cards::SetTextColor("", 5);//Resets Color to Default
        }
        if(!(PlArr[cind].CanPlayAny(lcard)) && lcard != "" )//Checks if a player can play any cards and if the lcard has a value
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<players[cind]<<" Can't Play Any Card! "<<endl;
            if(PlDraws(PlArr[cind], lcard, ctdp, mult, i, true, isBot) == 1)
                continue;//Makes Player Draw Cards and goes to the next turn if Draw 4 or Draw 2 is causing the drawing
        }
        acs = PlArr[cind].AllCards.size();
        if(!isBot)//If The Player isnt a bot
        {
            cout<<"\n\n"<<players[cind]<<"'s Cards:\n";
            int scw = ss.getWidth();
            PlArr[cind].Display(cl, cw, scw);//Displays All Cards of the Player with 1 based indexes(i.e 1, 2, 3,.., n)
            SafeCin(("\n\nEnter the the Index of the Card to Play: \n1 Being the Leftmost Card and " + to_string(acs) + " Being the Rightmost Card\nEnter " + to_string(acs + 1) + " For Drawing\n"), "\nThis Option Doesn't Exist", ctp, 1, acs + 1);//Gets The Card to Play Based on Index
        }
        else
        {
            int nxtcl = PlArr[order[(i + 1 >= Cards::count ? i + 1 - Cards::count : i + 1)]].AllCards.size();//Gets Number of Cards of the Next Player in Order
            ctdp = PlArr[cind].CardChoice(ctp, lcard, ctdp, nxtcl, o7);//Gets New Card To Display and selected card index 0 based and o7 index if 07 is Played
            ctp++;//Makes ctp 1 based index
        }
        if(ctp == acs + 1)//If Player Chooses To Draw Cards instead of Playing
        {
            PlDraws(PlArr[cind], lcard, ctdp, mult, i, false, isBot);//Makes Player Draws till They are Able to Play
            continue;//Goes to The next turn
        }
        if(!(Cards::CanPlay(PlArr[cind].AllCards[ctp - 1], lcard)) && lcard != "")//If The Selected Card Cant Be Played and lcard has value
        {
            cout<<"\nThis Card Can't be Played"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        lcard = PlArr[cind].AllCards[ctp - 1];//Sets new lcard based on selected card
        if(!isBot)//if it isnt a bot ctdp is updated(as ctdp is by default updated when .CardChoice is called)
            ctdp = lcard;
        PlArr[cind].Remove(ctp - 1);//Removes The Played Card From Current Players Cards
        cout<<"\n"<<players[cind]<<" Played: \n";
        Cards::Display(ctdp, cl, cw + 2, ctp, space);//Displays The Played Card
        if(Cards::AllStatus[cind] == "WON!!!")//If Current Player Has Won It Breaks From The Infinite Loop
            break;
        if(O7SpM(PlArr, players, order, lcard, i, o7cond, isBot, o7) == 1)
            continue;
        SpCard(order, i, mult, lcard, ctdp, isBot);
        i++;//Goes To The next Index in Order
    }
    WinningMessage(players[cind] + " WON THE GAME!!!");
}
void Rules()
{
    Clear();
    UpdateLengths();
    int scw = ss.getWidth();//Gets scw as cw = (scw * widf)/Div, therefore scw = (cw * Div) / widf
    //int sp = (23 * scw) / 50;//stores sp that is the no. of spaces to print before displaying card
    Fill f2('-'), f;//f2 objects fills empty space with -, f fills empty space with ' '
    cout<<f2.fwcent("RULES", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<"\n"<<f.fwcent("1) To Play A Card You Will Be Required To Enter Indexes Which Will Be Displayed On Top Of Card or Before The Card Based On Display Modes", scw)<<endl;//Centeres The String by filling remaining spaces before and after the string
    cout<<f.fwcent("2) Some Of These Indexes Will Change After Every Round As They Are Automatically Sorted By Color", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<f.fwcent("3) There Are 4 Colors: Pink, Green, Blue, Yellow", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<f.fwcent("4) Any Wild Card Allows You To Change Color", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<f.fwcent("5) DRAW 4 Stacks But Only On Other Draw 4s", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<f.fwcent("6) DRAW 2 Stacks But Only On Other Draw 2s", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<f.fwcent("7) If 7-0 Mode Is Enabled 7 Switches Your Hand With 1 Selected Player, And 0 Switches All Hands Based On Turn Order", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<f.fwcent("8) You Can Draw Cards Instead Of Playing A Card On Your Turn, But This Will Lead To Drawing Until A Drawn Card Is Playable On The Previously Played Card And Will Skip Your Turn", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\n"<<f.fwcent("****THERE ARE 2 DISPLAY MODE FOR CARDS:****", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<"\n"<<f.fwcent("Mode 1) If There Are Less Then Or Equal To 3 Rows Of Cards", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    Cards::Display("Wild Draw 4", cl, cw + 2, 1, space);//Display Wild Draw 4 with cl and cw
    cout<<"\n\n"<<f.fwcent("Mode 2) If There is More Then 3 Rows Of Cards", scw)<<endl;
    cout<<"\n"<<f.fillwith("", (scw - 12) / 2);
    Cards::Display("Wild Draw 4", 1, 1, 1, space);//Displays Wild Draw 4 as [ 1) Wild Draw 4 ]
    cout<<"\n\n\n"<<f2.fwcent("RULES", scw)<<endl;
    Stopper();
}
void Begin(Cards arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Cards::count; i++)
       arr[i].Draw(6);//Calls Draw n for each Cards Object to Start Every Player with n cards
}
void Orderfrom(int si, vector<int>& v)
{
    int isi = si, i = 0;//stores si in isi to limit i as si is used to add index till Cards::count
    while(si < Cards::count)
    { v.push_back(si); si++; }//adds si till si is less then Cards::count which is total number of objects
    while(i < isi)//starts adding from 0 till the initial si(isi)
    { v.push_back(i); i++; }
}
void getCardSize()
{
    int scl, scw;
    ss.getScreenSize(scl, scw);
    SafeCin("\nEnter Desired Card Length for Display Mode 1 (0 for Default): ", "\nNon-Numerical Values or Values Below 0 Not Allowed!", cl, 0, numeric_limits<int>::max());//gets desired card length or lets user to let it be the default by entering 0
    SafeCin("\nEnter Desired Card Width for Display Mode 1 (0 for Default): ", "\nNon-Numerical Values or Values Below 0 Not Allowed!", cw, 0, numeric_limits<int>::max());//gets desired card width or lets user to let it be the default by entering 0
    if(cl != 0)//if it isnt default
        lenf = (cl * Div) / scl;//it finds the new factors to make the selected length change with screen size
    if(cw != 0)
        widf = (cw * Div) / scw;
}
vector<string> setPlayers(int p, int b)
{
    vector<string> tore = setName("Player", p);//Gets Player names and stores it in tore
    if(b != 0)//if there are bots
    {
        vector<string> ta = setName("Bot", b);//Gets Names for Bots
        tore.insert(tore.end(), ta.begin(), ta.end());//Adds Bots Names to the end of Player Names
    }
    return tore;
}
vector<string> setName(string ty, int n)
{
    Clear();
    vector<string> v;
    string name;
    int c;
    SafeCin(("Do you Want to Enter " + ty + " Names: Yes(1)/ No(2) ?\nIf not (2) Entered " + ty + "s will be Named as " + ty + " n\n"), ("Invalid Choice!!\nEnter 1 for Entering Names and Enter 2 for Setting Names as " + ty + " n\n"), c, 1, 2);//Asks The User if the ty names should be set to default or user entered
    cin.ignore();//To Make sure getline can be used
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        Clear();
        if(c == 1)//If User Entered
        {
            cout<<"Enter Name for "<<ty<<" "<<i<<": ";//Asks the user for i'th ty name
            getline(cin, name);//stores the user entered name in string name
        }
        else//If default
            name = ty + " " + to_string(i);//Stores name as ty i
        v.push_back(name);//Adds ty name to vector v
    }
    return v;
}
void GetStatus(vector<string> n, int si)
{
    cout<<"All Player Status: \n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < Cards::count; i++)//Loops through Cards::count times
    {
        if(si == Cards::count) si = 0;//if starting index hits Cards::count, it resets it to 0
        string ta = (i != (Cards::count - 1)) ? ", " : "\n";//Sets Seperator to \n if the last status is being printed else it sets it to ", "
        cout<<n[si]<<": "<<Cards::AllStatus[si]<<ta;//Displays The Player Name Followed by Players Status and Finally The Seperator
        si++;//Goes To The Next Index
    }
}
void PrintOrder(vector<int> oi, vector<string> pn, int si)
{
    cout<<"\nTurn Order: \n\n";
    int c = oi.size();//c is the count for the number of players
    while(c != 0)
    {
        if(si == oi.size())//if si hits oi.size() it resets si to 0 tis to prit from si to oi.size and then from 0 to si
            si = 0;
        string ta = (c == 1) ? "\n" : " ----> ";//If Count is 1 i.e it is the last player is being printed the seperator is turned to \n
        cout<<pn[oi[si]]<<ta;//Prints Player Names Based on Turn Order
        si++; c--;//Goes to the next si and reduces c
    }
}
void PlusN(int n)
{
    Fill f; MgTxt m;
    cout<<endl;
    m.PrintWTxt(f.fillwith("", space), "+" + to_string(n));//Prints +n Magnified with preceeding spaces
}
void ReverseOrder(vector<int>& v, int& p)
{
    int cele = v[p];//stores the original index
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());//reverses the entire turn order
    p = find(v.begin(), v.end(), cele) - v.begin();//gets the new position of original index
}
void SwitchWith(Cards& plt, Cards& plf)
{
    vector<string> Temp = plt.AllCards;//Stores plt in Temp to later exchange
    plt.AllCards = plf.AllCards;//Sets the value of plt to plf
    plt.UpdateStatus();//Updates plt's status
    plf.AllCards = Temp;//Sets plf as Temp
    plf.UpdateStatus();//Updates plf's Status
}
void SwitchAll(Cards arr[], vector<int> ord)
{
    /*This is Better Explained With an Example Say,
     *ord = {4, 3, 2, 1, 0} and Cards = {"8 cards", "6 cards", "7 cards", "2 cards", "4 cards"}//Though it switches AllCards I am using Status for Simplicity
     *say card is already sorted based on ord even though in reality it is accessed while switching
     *therefore Cards = {"4 cards", "2 cards", "7 cards", "6 cards", "8 cards"}
     *l will be 4 this prevents out of bounds within the loop
     *c = "4 cards", c2 = "2 cards"
     Within Loop condition i < (l viz 4)
     *i = 1; Cards[1] = c = "4 cards"; c = "7 cards", c2 is same; new Cards = {"4 cards", "4 cards", "7 cards", "6 cards", "8 cards"}
     *i = 2; Cards[2] = c2 = "2 cards"; c is same, c2 = "6 cards"; new Cards = {"4 cards", "4 cards", "2 cards", "6 cards", "8 cards"}
     *i = 3; Cards[3] = c = "7 cards"; c = "8 cards", c2 is same; new Cards = {"4 cards", "4 cards", "2 cards", "7 cards", "8 cards"}
     *i = 4; condition false; Last Values c = "8 cards", c2 = "6 cards"
     Outside Loop
     *Cards[4] = c2 = "6 cards"; new Cards = {"4 cards", "4 cards", "2 cards", "7 cards", "6 cards"}
     *Cards[0] = c = "8 cards"; new Cards = {"8 cards", "4 cards", "2 cards", "7 cards", "6 cards"}
     Therefore this uses two containers to alternatively store values and switch values*/
    int l = ord.size() - 1;
    vector<string> c = arr[ord[0]].AllCards, c2 = arr[ord[1]].AllCards;
    for(int i = 1; i < l; i++)
    {
        arr[ord[i]].AllCards = (i % 2 == 1) ? c : c2;
        arr[ord[i]].UpdateStatus();//update status is called to reflect the new changes after switching
        if(i % 2 == 1)
            c = arr[ord[i + 1]].AllCards;
        else
            c2 = arr[ord[i + 1]].AllCards;
    }
    arr[ord[l]].AllCards = (l % 2 == 1) ? c : c2;
    arr[ord[0]].AllCards = (l % 2 == 0) ? c : c2;
    arr[ord[l]].UpdateStatus(); arr[ord[0]].UpdateStatus();
}
void SpCard(vector<int>& o, int& ind, int& m, string& c, string& ctdp, bool ib)
{
    string n = Cards::getNum(c);//Gets the number part of the card this is to check if the card is special
    if(Cards::getColor(c) == "Wild" && !ib)//If te card is wild and it isnt a bot it asks the user for a new color
    {
        int ch;
        SafeCin("\nChoose a New Color by Index: \n1) Pink, 2) Blue, 3) Green, 4) Yellow\n", "\nOnly Indexes 1 to 4 Allowed", ch, 1, 4);//gets color through index
        string carr[4] = {"Pink ", "Blue ", "Green ", "Yellow "};//array used to directly access color
        ctdp = carr[ch - 1] + n;//changes the card to display to the card with user selected color i.e for wild draw 4 and pink choosen it sets o pink draw 4
    }
    if(n == "Reverse")
        ReverseOrder(o, ind);//Calls Reverse order if the card is reverse
    else if(n == "Skip")
        ind++;//increments the index as the index is incremented at the end of main loop therefore skipping the next index in order
    else if(n == "Draw 2")
        m += 2;//increases m by 2 therefore increasing the to draw stack by 2
    else if(n == "Draw 4")
        m += 4;//increases m by 4 therefore increasing the to draw stack by 4
    else if(n == "Color Changer")
        c = ctdp;//it immediately changes last card to ctdp as wild color changer only changes color
}
int PlDraws(Cards& pl, string& c, string ctdp, int& m, int& ind, bool sm, bool ib)
{
    cout<<"\nThey Will Draw ";
    if(m != 0)//If There is an active to draw stack
    {
        cout<<m<<" Cards "<<endl;
        pl.Draw(m);//Draws m Cards for the player
        m = 0;//resets to draw stack
        if(!ib)//If the player isnt a bot it display all cards with new Cards Drawn
            pl.Display(cl, cw, (cw * Div) / widf);
        if(c == "Wild Draw 4")//If The Card that caused the draw is draw 4 it makes it inactive by switching it ctdp which has the selected color
            c = ctdp;
        else if(Cards::getNum(c) == "Draw 2")
            c = Cards::getColor(c) + " Draw2";//If it is draw 2 that caused the draw it makes it inactive by setting it to Draw2 to distinguish it from active Draw 2 which has space
        ind++;//Sets the ind to next turn to not let the player play
        return 1;//returns 1 to say to go to the next turn
    }
    else//If There is no stack that means player is forced to draw because they have no playable cards or they dont want to play a card
    {
        int ol = pl.AllCards.size(), nl;//Old Number of Cards is stored in ol and nl will be used to store new Number of Cards
        if(sm)//Shows This Message if they were forced to draw
            cout<<"Until They Are Able To Play!"<<endl;
        else//If They choose to draw it skips their turn
            ind++;
        pl.DrawTCP(c);//It Draws Cards Until They Are Able To Play A Card on last card(c)
        nl = pl.AllCards.size();
        cout<<"\nThey Drew "<<(nl - ol)<<" Cards! \n";//Shows the number of cards drawn
        if(!ib)//If it isnt a bot it displays last displayed card
        {
            cout<<"\nLast Drawn Card: \n";
            Cards::Display(pl.AllCards[nl - 1], cl, cw + 2, nl, space);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
int O7SpM(Cards arr[], vector<string> pl, vector<int> o, string c, int& i, bool o7, bool ib, int o7i)
{
    string n = Cards::getNum(c);//Gets the number part of the card this is to check if the card is 0 or 7
    if(!o7 || (n != "0" && n != "7"))//if the card neither 0 nor 7 or if 0-7 mode is disabled it does nothig and returns 0
        return 0;
    if(n == "7")
    {
        int ind = o7i;//o7i is the index that bot chooses it is entered as -1 for player
        if(!ib)//If the player isnt a bot
        {
            string pwi = "\nEnter Index of the Player You Want to Switch With: \n";
            for(int j = 0; j < Cards::AllStatus.size(); j++)
            {
                if(o[i] == j)
                    continue;
                pwi += to_string(j + 1) + ") " + pl[j] + " : " + Cards::AllStatus[j] + "\n";
            }
            SafeCin(pwi, "\nIndex Out of Bounds!!", ind, 1, o.size());//Asks for index on the basis of index displayed above
            ind--;
            while(ind == o[i])
            {
                cout<<Cards::SetTextColor("Pink ", -1)<<"\nIndex Doesn't Exist"<<Cards::SetTextColor("", 5)<<endl;
                SafeCin(pwi, "\nIndex Out of Bounds!!", ind, 1, o.size());
                ind--;
            }
        }
        SwitchWith(arr[o[i]], arr[ind]);//Switches Current Players Card with the Selected Index
        cout<<"\n"<<pl[o[i]]<<" Exchanged Cards With "<<pl[ind]<<"\n";//Shows which player switched card with which player
    }
    else//If it is 0 it switches all cards using SwitchAll() function
    { cout<<"\n"<<pl[o[i]]<<" Exchanged All Cards \n"; SwitchAll(arr, o); }
    if(!ib)//If The Player isnt a bot It shows them the new hand After Exchanging
    {
        cout<<"\nNew Hand: "<<endl;
        arr[o[i]].Display(cl, cw, (cw * Div) / widf);
    }
    return 0;
}
void SafeCin(string msg, string err, int& i, int ll, int ul)
{
    cout<<msg;//Displays the message to let user know what is expected
    cin>>i;//Gets the input
    bool cond = (i < ll) || (i > ul);//finds if input is outside limits
    while(cin.fail() || cond)//loops while cin fails or cond is true
    {
        cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');//Clears Buffer and ignores everything till \n
        cout<<Cards::SetTextColor("Wild ", 1)<<err<<endl;//Displays Error Message With Pink Color
        cout<<Cards::SetTextColor("", 5)<<msg;//Displays message Again with defalt colors
        cin>>i; cond = (i < ll) || (i > ul);//Gets the input again and checks for cond again
    }
}
void UpdateLengths()
{
    int sl, sw;
    ss.getScreenSize(sl, sw);//Gets Screen Height and Width and Stores it in sl and sw, respectively.
    cl = (sl * lenf) / Div; cw = (sw * widf) / Div; space = (sw - cw) / 2;//Gets cl, cw and space using screen size, lenf, widf
}
void Clear()
{
    #if defined(_WIN32)
    system("cls");//If os is windows it executes "cls"
    #else
    system("clear");//else it executes "clear"
    #endif
}
void Stopper()
{
    string _;
    cout<<"\nEnter Anything to Continue: ";
    cin.ignore();//Makes sure /n doesnt bleed over from cin so that user can enter
    getline(cin, _);
    Clear();//Clears Screen
}
void WinningMessage(string mssg)
{
    string stemp = "";//stores parts of the mssg, this is to display every word in new line
    Fill f;
    cout<<"\n\n\nRESULTS:\n\n";
    int scw = ss.getWidth();
    scw = scw / 2;//halfs scw to fill with ' '
    for(int i = 0; i <= mssg.size(); i++)
    {
        if(mssg[i] == ' ' || i == mssg.size())//If it is a space or if it is the last character
        {
            MgTxt m;//Instance of MgTxt to magnify text
            cout<<endl;//Starts with a new line
            string* pt = m.getPrArr(stemp);//Gets Pointer To The Array That Stores 5 lines of Magnified Text
            stemp = "";//empties stemp
            for(int j = 0; j < MgTxt::Size; j++)//Goes Through the Array
            {
                cout<<f.fillwith("", (scw - (pt->size() / 2)))<<Cards::SetTextColor("Wild ", (j % 4) + 1)<<*pt;//Fills with total of (scw - pt.size() / 2) spaces followed by changing text color and then printing j + 1 th line of the text
                pt++;//makes pt point to the next element
            }
            continue;//continues to next iteration to not include ' '
        }
        stemp += mssg[i];//adds characters to stemp
    }
    cout<<Cards::SetTextColor("", 5);//Sets Color to Default
}
```

**Card.hpp**

This is used to create a class with all functions of a card that is drawing cards, removing cards, displaying cards, etc.

```
#include "Fill.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

class Cards
{
    private:
        static string colors[5];//Stores All Possible Colors for UNO Cards
        static string pcards[15];//Store All Possible Cards(excluding Color Combinations i.e it Stores 2 instead of Red 2)
        int index;//Stores the index of an Card Object wrt All Created Card Objects(i.e 1st object will have index 0)
        static bool SameNum(string a, string b)//Checks if 2 cards have Same Number
        {
            string sub1 = getNum(a), sub2 = getNum(b);//Gets Number of each card and stores it in sub1 and sub2
            if(sub1 == pcards[10] && sub2 == "Draw2")
                return true;//Card has num Draw2 if Draw 2 has Resulted in Someone Drawing Cards (i.e It Allows for Draw 2 on an Already Completed Draw 2)
            return (sub1 == sub2);//returns true if Both have Same nums else return false
        }
        static bool SameColor(string a, string b)//Checks If Both Cards have Same Colors
        {
            string sub1 = getColor(a), sub2 = getColor(b);//Gets Colors for Both Cards
            if(b == (colors[4] + " " + pcards[11]) && Cards::getNum(a) == pcards[12])
                return false;//If Last Card(b) is Wild Draw 4 and a is Wild Color Changer it returns false
            if(getNum(b) == pcards[10])
                return false;//If Last Card(b) is Draw 2 it returns false Therefore Only Allowing other draw 2s
            if(sub1 == colors[4])
                return true;//If a's Color is Wild and Last Card(b) isnt a Draw 2(see previous condition), it returns true
            return (sub1 == sub2);//returns true or false based on if the colors are same
        }
        static void Display(vector<string> ac, int si, int l, int w, int s)
        {//Displays All Cards in ac, with length l, width w, after 's' spaces, Display Indexes Of the Cards Based on si
            if(w < 13 || l < 5)//as the largest
                return Display(ac, si);
            cout<<endl;
            int tb = w/12, ts = tb, coln, pcn, cent = (l - 1)/2;//tb and ts stores number of spaces in between cards, coln and pcn cycles through colors and pcards, cent stores the center line
            Fill f('-'), f2;//Creates Fill Objects to Fill Space with '-' for f and ' ' for f2
            string spacer = "", spacerb = "";
            while(s != 0)//Loops through Based on s to Get the Number of spaces before Starting to Display Cards
            { spacerb += ' '; s--; }
            while(ts != 0)//Loops through Based on ts to Get the spacer Between Cards
            { spacer += ' '; ts--; }
            if(si > 0)//If si is Non Negative it Enters the Indexes to display
            {
                cout<<spacerb;
                for(int i = 0; i < ac.size(); i++)//Limits number of indexes to Number of Cards(ac.size())
                {
                    int totl = 1 + w + tb;//w + 1 is the width of the card and tb is space in between cards
                    cout<<f2.fwcent(si, totl);//Centers si and fills the rest of the space based on totl
                    si++;//Goes to the next index
                }
            }
            cout<<endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)//Loops through all Lines Based on the length of the card
            {
                coln = 0; pcn = 0;
                string beg = (i == 0 || i == (l- 1)) ? " " : "|";//starts with " " if its the first or last line else starts with "|"
                cout<<spacerb<<SetTextColor(ac[0], 4)<<beg;//spaces each line based on spacerb
                for(int j = 0; j < ac.size(); j++)//Loops through the Cards
                {
                    if(i == 0 || i == (l - 1))//if its the first or last line
                        cout<<SetTextColor(ac[j], (i == 0 ? 1 : 2))<<f.fillwith("", w);//fills with '-' based on w
                    else if(i == 1 || i == (l - 2))//if its second or second last line
                    {
                        cout<<SetTextColor(ac[j], 5)<<f2.fwcent(getColor(ac[coln]), w);//prints and centers the card color based on w
                        coln++;//goes to the next cards color
                    }
                    else if(i == cent)//if its the center line
                    {
                        cout<<SetTextColor(ac[j], 5)<<f2.fwcent(getNum(ac[pcn]), w);//Centers Card's Number based on w
                        pcn++;//goes to the next cards pcards
                    }
                    else
                        cout<<f2.fillwith("", w);//Fills with ' ' based on w
                    cout<<SetTextColor(ac[j], 3)<<beg<<spacer;//Ends with beg and adds spacer in between cards
                    if(j == (ac.size() - 1))
                        cout<<endl;//if it is the last card it goes to the next line after printing that line
                }
            }
            cout<<SetTextColor("", 5);//resets text color so that anything printing next is in the default color
        }
        static void Display(vector<string> ac, int si)//Displays AllCards in a simpler fashion i.e [n) Wild Draw 4, n + 1) Red 2, ...]
        {
            cout<<"[ ";
            bool isNeg = si < 0;//If Starting Index(si) Is Negative It Does Not Display Indexes
            for(int i = 0; i < ac.size(); i++)
            {
                string ce = (i != (ac.size() - 1)) ? ", " : " ]\n";//Sets ce with a seperator it becomes " ]\n" If Its The Last Card
                string sind = isNeg ? "" : to_string(si) + ") ";//Stores Card Index or Keeps it Empty Based on isNeg
                if(getColor(ac[i]) == colors[4])//Checks if the Card Is Wild
                {
                    cout<<SetTextColor(ac[i], (rand() % 4) + 1)<<sind;//Displays The Index With 1 Random Color
                    for(int j = 0; j < ac[i].size(); j++)//Loops Through Characters of The Card
                        cout<<SetTextColor(ac[i], (j % 4 + 1))<<ac[i][j];//Displays Each Character With A Color In Order
                    cout<<SetTextColor("", 5)<<ce;//Displays Seperator with Default Color
                }
                else
                    cout<<SetTextColor(ac[i], 5)<<sind<<ac[i]<<SetTextColor("", 5)<<ce;//Displays The Index And Card With The Cards Color Followed By The Seperator With The Default Color
                si++;
            }
        }
    public:
        static vector<string>  AllStatus;//Stores Status(i.e number of Cards or uno or won) of All Card Objects
        vector<string> AllCards;//Stores All Cards of a Cards Object
        static int count;//Counts the number of Cards Objects
        Cards()
        {
            srand(time(0));//To make random against time
            count++;//Increases count every time object is created
            AllStatus.push_back("");//creates empty status when an object is created
            index = count - 1;//sets index of an object as (count at the moment at creation) - 1
        }
        static void Display(string card, int l, int w, int si, int sp)
        {//Display card 'card' of length l, width w, index(to be displayed) si, and number of spaces based on sp
            vector<string> st;
            st.push_back(card);//pushes back 'card' to st
            Display(st, si, l, w, sp);//passes st and other parameters to private static void Display(vector<string>, int, int, int, int)
        }
        void Display(int l, int w, int scw)//Displays cards in AllCards based on length l, width w, and screen width scw
        {
            int sp = w/12, noac = ((scw - sp - 1) / (w + sp + 1));//sp is the number of spaces between each card and, noac is Number Of Allowed Cards
            /*sp is space between cards, sep is seperator between cards which is either '|' or ' ' and c represents cards
             as cards are displayed as : sp sep c sp sep c ... sp sep, we know if in a row there are n cards there will be n + 1 sp and n + 1 sep, we also know that the sum of all cards width, sp and sep should be less than or equal to scw, we also know te size of sep will always be 1
            Therefore, (n * w) + (n + 1)(sp) + (n + 1) <= scw, nw + nsp + sp + n + 1 <= scw, n(w + sp + 1) + sp + 1 <= scw,
            n(w + sp + 1) <= (scw - sp - 1), n <= (scw - sp - 1) / (w + sp + 1)
            As int drops all decimals and we want maximum value of n we can drop '<' and use the formula noac = (scw - sp - 1) / (w + sp + 1)*/
            if(AllCards.size() > (noac * 3))//if number of cards  cant be displayed in 3 rows or if card width is less than 13 it calls void Display()
                return Display(AllCards, 1);
            vector<string> subac;//Stores sub vectors from AllCards
            int i = 1;
            while(i <= AllCards.size())
            {
                string s = AllCards[i - 1];
                subac.push_back(s);
                if((i % noac) == 0)//If number of cards it has already added is a multiple of 8
                {
                    cout<<endl;//goes to new line to make sure every 8 cards are one below the other
                    Display(subac, (i - (noac - 1)), l, w, sp);//Displays the current subac (with 8 cards)
                    subac.clear();//empties the vector
                }
                i++;
            }
            if(!subac.empty())//if subac still has cards within it, it Displays them
            { cout<<endl; Display(subac, (i - subac.size()), l, w, sp); }
        }
        void Draw()//Adds a card to AllCards
        {
            int coln = rand() % 4;//gets a random index from 0 to 3 to get a random color other then "Wild"
            int pcn = rand() % 15;//gets a random index from 0 to 14 to get a random pcards
            string colorpart = colors[coln], numpart = pcards[pcn];//gets the numpart and colorpart from colors and pcards based on coln and pcn
            if(pcn == 11 || pcn == 12)//if pcn is the index of Color Changer or Draw 4 it sets colorpart as "Wild"
                colorpart = colors[4];
            AllCards.push_back((colorpart + " " + numpart));//Adds the colorpart and numpart with " " to AllCards hence generating a new card
            UpdateStatus();
        }
        void Draw(int n)//Calls Draw() n times
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                Draw();
        }
        void DrawTCP(string lcard)//Calls Draw unless it finds a playable card based on lcard
        {
            bool cond = false;//set to false to draw at least once
            while(!cond)
            {
                Draw();
                cond = CanPlay(AllCards[AllCards.size() - 1], lcard);
            }
        }
        void Remove(int ind)//Removes a card from AllCards at index ind
        {
            if(ind > AllCards.size() || ind < 0)//if index is out of bounds it does nothing
                return;
            AllCards.erase((AllCards.begin() + ind));//.erase removes an element using iterators .begin() points to index 0 adding ind makes it point to the element at index
            UpdateStatus();//gets new status after removing card
        }
        void Sort()//Sorts AllCards based on color
        {
            int s = AllCards.size();//gets the size before adding anything
            vector<string> r, g, b, y;//creating vectors for colors red, green, blue, yellow, respectfully
            for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)//goes through the original cards of AllCards(i.e before s)
            {
                string col = getColor(AllCards[i]);//gets colors for card at i
                if(col == colors[0])//if color for the current card is Red it adds the card at i to r
                    r.push_back(AllCards[i]);
                else if(col == colors[1])//if color for the current card is Green it adds the card at i to g
                    g.push_back(AllCards[i]);
                else if(col == colors[2])//if color for the current card is Blue it adds the card at i to b
                    b.push_back(AllCards[i]);
                else if(col == colors[3])//if color for the current card is Red it adds the card at i to y
                    y.push_back(AllCards[i]);
                else//if it is Wild it adds it directly to AllCards to save space and time
                    AllCards.push_back(AllCards[i]);
            }
            AllCards.erase(AllCards.begin(), AllCards.begin() + s);//Erases the original cards
            AllCards.reserve((AllCards.size() + r.size() + g.size() + b.size() + y.size()));//reserves sum of vectors and remaining AllCards
            AllCards.insert(AllCards.end(), r.begin(), r.end());//inserts all red cards(stored in r) at the end of AllCards
            AllCards.insert(AllCards.end(), g.begin(), g.end());//inserts all green cards(stored in g) at the end of AllCards
            AllCards.insert(AllCards.end(), b.begin(), b.end());//inserts all blue cards(stored in b) at the end of AllCards
            AllCards.insert(AllCards.end(), y.begin(), y.end());//inserts all yellow cards(stored in y) at the end of AllCards
        }
        static bool CanPlay(string selcard, string lcard)//Checks if selcard can be played on lcard
        { return (SameColor(selcard, lcard) || SameNum(selcard, lcard)); }
        bool CanPlayAny(string lcard)//Checks if any of cards from AllCards can be played on lcard
        {
            for(string s : AllCards)//Loops through AllCards
            {
                if(CanPlay(s, lcard))//checks if current card can be played on lcard
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        static string getNum(string card)//gets Number of a card(i.e pcards)
        {
            int nst = card.find(' ') + 1, size1 = card.length() - nst;
            //' ' seperates color and num so index after num is the start of num which is stored in nst, the size of num is total size - size of color + 1 viz equal to nst
            string sub = card.substr(nst, size1);//creates a substring starting from nst of size size1
            return sub;
        }
        static string getColor(string card)
        {
            int size1 = card.find(' ');//as ' ' seperates color and num, the index of ' ' will be equal to size of color
            string sub = card.substr(0, size1);//creates a substring starting from 0 (as color of a card is first) of size size1
            return sub;
        }
        void UpdateStatus()
        {
            int s = AllCards.size();//gets the number of cards
            if(s == 0 || s == 1)//if number of cards is 0 or 1
                AllStatus[index] = s == 0 ? "WON!!!" : "UNO!!";//Updates Staus of the Current Object as WON if s is 0, or UNO if s is 1
            else
                AllStatus[index] = to_string(s) + " Cards";//Updates Staus of the Current Object
        }
        static string SetTextColor(string card, int l)
        {
            string o = "\x1B[", s = "Color 0";//o is for linux and it stores ansi sequence to set color, s is for windows and it uses System command to Set Color
            if(getColor(card) == colors[0] || (getColor(card) == colors[4] && l == 1))//Pink or Wild and 1
            { o += "35m"; s += "C"; }//Pink
            else if(getColor(card) == colors[1] || (getColor(card) == colors[4] && l == 2))//Green or Wild and 2
            { o += "92m"; s += "A"; }//Green
            else if(getColor(card) == colors[2] || (getColor(card) == colors[4] && l == 3))//Blue or Wild and 1
            { o += "94m"; s += "9"; }//Blue
            else if(getColor(card) == colors[3] || (getColor(card) == colors[4] && l == 4))//Yellow or Wild and 1
            { o += "93m"; s += "E"; }//Yellow
            else if(l == 5)//Anything Else and If l = 5
            { o += "0m"; s += "F"; }//Default
            #if defined(_WIN32)
                system(s.c_str());
                return "";//Returns Nothing As Windows Command Switches Color as Soon As system is executed
            #endif
            return o;//Returns o as it switches color when o is printed
        }
        string CardChoice(int& ci, string lcard, string ctdp, int nxtc, int& o7ind)
        {
            vector<string> plcard;//Stores All Playable Cards
            int diff = 3 + AllCards.size() - nxtc;//Incentive for Wild Based on The Number Of Cards Of The Current Player() and The Next Players Cards(nxtc)
            int colinc[5] = {5, 5, 5, 5, (diff < 3 ? -10 : diff)};//Sets All Colors Incentive as 5 and sets wild to -10 if Current Player Has Less Cards or Diff
            if(lcard != "")//Checks If Last Card is Empty
            {
                for(string s : AllCards)//Loops Through All Cards of the PLayer
                    if(CanPlay(s, lcard))//Checks If The Current Card Is Playable
                        plcard.push_back(s);//Adds The Card If It is PLayable
            }
            else//If Last Card Is Empty it Allows All Cards of The Player To Be Played
                plcard = AllCards;
            for(string s : AllCards)
                colinc[find(colors, end(colors), getColor(s)) - colors] += 1;//Increases Color's Incentive Each Time A Color Appears, To Incentivise Playing Cards of A Color Which A Player Has More Of
            int allinc[plcard.size()] = {0};//Makes An Array To Store Incentives For All Playable Cards and Sets It To 0
            for(int i = 0; i < plcard.size(); i++)
            {
                allinc[i] += colinc[find(colors, end(colors), getColor(plcard[i])) - colors];//Adds colinc To Each Cards Incentive Based On The Cards Color
                int pci = find(pcards, end(pcards), getNum(plcard[i])) - pcards;//Finds The Num(see pcards) of Each Card
                allinc[i] += (pci == 0 || pci == 7 || pci > 9) ? 1 : 0;//Checks If The Card is a special Card i.e 0, 7, Skip, Draw 2, Reverse, etc. And Incentives it slightly
            }
            int cdin = (max_element(allinc, allinc + (sizeof(allinc) / sizeof(allinc[0]))) - allinc);//Gets The Index From allinc for the card with The Most Incentive
            o7ind = -1;
            ctdp = plcard[cdin];//Sets The Card To Play To The Selected Card Based on cdin
            if(getColor(plcard[cdin]) == colors[4])
                ctdp = colors[max_element(colinc, (end(colinc) - 1)) - colinc] + " " + getNum(plcard[cdin]);//If The Card Is Wild it Sets The Color To the Color Which Is Found The Most in AllCards
            else if(getNum(plcard[cdin]) == pcards[7])//If The Num is 7
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < AllStatus.size(); i++)//Loops Through AllStatus Which Stores The Number of Cards or UNO!! or WON!!! In All Objects of Cards
                {
                    if(i == index)//Makes Sure It Does Not Try To Exchange With Itself
                        continue;
                    if(AllStatus[i] == "UNO!!")//If It Finds A Player With UNO!! It selects that Player
                    {
                        o7ind = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(o7ind == -1)//If it is -1 i.e No Index Has Been Stored It Stores The First Possible Index
                        o7ind = i;
                    else if( stoi(getColor(AllStatus[i])) < stoi(getColor(AllStatus[o7ind])) )
                        o7ind = i;
                    /*getColor Essentially Gets All Character Before ' ' which In AllStatus Will Be Number of Cards it Converts it To int to Compare if The
                     Previously Stored Index's Number of Cards is Less Then The Current Index's Number of Cards, If Thats True It Changes o7ind to i*/
                }
            }
            ci = find(AllCards.begin(), AllCards.end(), plcard[cdin]) - AllCards.begin();//It Finds The Index of The Selected Card
            return ctdp;//Returns Selected Card With Choosen Color if Wild
        }
};
//Initializes static members
int Cards::count = 0;
string Cards::colors[5] = {"Pink", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Wild"};
string Cards::pcards[15] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Draw 2", "Draw 4", "Color Changer", "Skip", "Reverse"};
vector<string> Cards::AllStatus = {};
```

**Fill.hpp**

This is used to fill a certain length with the given value and rest of the length with selected character, it can also center the value and fill its left and right side with a selected character.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Fill
{
    private:
        bool isNum(string st)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++)
            {
                int asc = (int) st[i];
                bool cond = (asc >= 48 && asc <= 57);//stores if this char is a digit
                if(i == 0)
                    cond = (cond || (asc == 45));//allows for - at position 0(representing negative number)
                if(i != (st.length() - 1) && i != 0)
                {
                    bool cond2 = (asc == 46);
                    cond = (cond || cond2);//allows for . at any point other then the first or last character
                    count += cond2 ? 1 : 0;//keeps count of number of . character
                }
                if(!cond || count > 1)//if cond is false or if the number has more then 1 decimal place it is considered invalid
                    return false;
                //as cond will only be false if the char is non numerical or negative sign appears in any position other then the starting position or if the number starts or ends with a decimal point
            }
            return true;
        }
        void RemUz(string& str)
        {
            size_t si = str.find(".");//finds the index of '.' to see if the num has decimal places
            size_t lnfz = str.find_last_not_of("0");//gets the index of last non-zero before all zereos
            if(lnfz != string::npos && si != string::npos)//If the num has decimals and useless zereos
                str.erase(lnfz + 1);//removes all useless zereos
            if(str[str.length() - 1] == '.')//if the last element is a decimal remove the decimal
                str.pop_back();
        }
        template<typename T>
        string PStringV(T d)//converts any data type to string using string stream to get accuarate precisions
        {
            stringstream stream;//creates a new string stream
            stream<<fixed<<setprecision(prec)<<d;//adds d or a float types to string stream with precision set to prec
            return stream.str();//converts stream to string
        }
    public:
        char ta = ' ';//stores the char that will be used to fill remaining space(default: ' ')
        int prec = 6;//stores precision for float and double types(default 6 decimal spaces)
        int n = 10;
        char trs = '+', brs = '+', rs = '|', trf = '-', brf = '-';
        //Constructors
        Fill(){ }
        Fill(int p)//sets user prefferred precision
        { prec = p; }
        Fill(char c)//sets user prefferred ta
        { ta = c; }
        Fill(int p, char c)//sets user prefferred ta & precision
        { ta = c; prec = p;}

        //Functions
        template<typename T>
        string fillwith(T val, int als)
        {
            string st = PStringV(val);
            string s = "";//creates empty s with every call
            if(isNum(st))//checks if s stores a number
                RemUz(st);//Removes trailing zereos from decimals
            int n = als - st.length();
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                s += ta;
            s = st + s;//returns the string(i.e any input of any function) and the filled space
            return s;//i.e for fillwith("ab", 9) ta = '+' it will return string "ab+++++++"
        }
        template<typename T>
        string fillwith(T st, string alst)
        { return fillwith(st, alst.length()); }//takes string and calculates its length and passes the data to fillwith(string, int)
        //Centered
        template<typename T>
        string fwcent(T val, int als)
        {
            string st = PStringV(val);
            if(isNum(st))//Removes useless 0
                RemUz(st);
            string toret;//stores the string to return
            int l = st.length(), size1 = l/2, size2 = ceil((float)l/2.0);//to divide the string into two halfs to center it
            int si1 = 0, si2 = size1;//starting index for first half will be 0 and the second half will be size1
            string ss1 = st.substr(si1, size1), ss2 = st.substr(si2, size2);//divides st based on above data
            int tf1 = als/2 - ss1.length(), tf2 = ceil((float)als/2.0);
            toret = fillwith("", tf1) + ss1 + fillwith(ss2, tf2);
            return toret;
        }
        template<typename T>
        string fwcent(T st, string alst)
        { return fwcent(st, alst.length()); }
};
```

**MagnTxt.hpp**

This is used to magnify almost all characters to 5 lines

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MgTxt
{
    private:
        static std::string MagLett[59][5];
        static char NormLett[59];
        std::string sp = "         ";
        std::string sep = "   ";
        std::string Tp[5] = {"", "", "", "", ""};
        void MagTxt(std::string s)
        {
            for(char c : s)
            {
                c = std::toupper(c);
                if(c == ' ')
                {
                    Tp[0] += sp; Tp[1] += sp;
                    Tp[2] += sp; Tp[3] += sp;
                    Tp[4] += sp;
                }
                else
                {
                    char* cind = std::find(std::begin(NormLett), std::end(NormLett), c);
                    if(cind == std::end(NormLett))
                        continue;
                    int ind = cind - std::begin(NormLett);
                    for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
                        Tp[j] += MagLett[ind][j] + sep;
                }
            }
            Tp[0] += "\n"; Tp[1] += "\n"; Tp[2] += "\n"; Tp[3] += "\n"; Tp[4] += "\n";
        }
    public:
        static int Size;
        MgTxt()
        { Tp[0] = ""; Tp[1] = ""; Tp[2] = ""; Tp[3] = ""; Tp[4] = ""; }
        template<typename T>
        std::string* getPrArr(T val)
        {
            std::stringstream stream; stream<<val;
            std::string st = stream.str();
            MagTxt(st);
            return Tp;
        }
        template<typename T>
        void PrintMT(T val, int up)
        {
            if(up == 1)
                getPrArr(val);
            for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
                std::cout<<Tp[i];
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }
        template<typename T>
        void PrintMT(T val)
        { PrintMT(val, 1); }
        template<typename T>
        void PrintWTxt(std::string ta, T val, int up)
        {
            if(up == 1)
                getPrArr(val);
            for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
                std::cout<<ta<<Tp[i];
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }
        template<typename T>
        void PrintWTxt(std::string ta, T val)
        { return PrintWTxt(ta, val, 1); }
};
int MgTxt::Size = 5;
char MgTxt::NormLett[59] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '+', '-', '@', '_', '/', '!', '#', '?', '|', '\\', '%', '^', '[', ']', ':', ';', '{', '}', '(', ')', '.', '\'', '"'};
std::string MgTxt::MagLett[59][5] = {//Note:To See How That Letter Would Look Just Press Enter After The Commas And Align The ""
    {" ---- ", "|    |", "|    |", "|    |", " ---- "},//0
    {"  /|  ", "   |  ", "   |  ", "   |  ", " -----"},//1
    {" ---- ", "     |", " ---- ", "|     ", " ---- "},//2
    {" ---- ", "     |", " ---- ", "     |", " ---- "},//3
    {"|     ", "|     ", " ---- ", "     |", "     |"},//4
    {" ---- ", "|     ", " ---- ", "     |", " ---- "}, //5
    {" ---- ", "|     ", " ---- ", "|    |", " ---- "},//6
    {" ----   ", "     |  ", "    ----", "     |  ", "     |  "}, //7
    {" ---- ", "|    |", " ---- ", "|    |", " ---- "},//8
    {" ---- ", "|    |", " ---- ", "     |", " ---- "}, //9
    {"          ", "    /\\    ", "   /  \\   ", "  /----\\  ", " /      \\ "},//A
    {" ____ ", "|    \\", "|____/", "|    \\", "|____/"},//B
    {" ____ ", "/     ", "|     ", "|     ", "\\____ "},//C
    {" ____  ", "|    \\ ", "|     \\", "|     /", "|____/ "},//D
    {" ---- ", "|     ", " ---- ", "|     ", " ---- "},//E
    {" ---- ", "|     ", " ---- ", "|     ", "|     "},//F
    {" ---- ", "|     ", "|  -- ", "| |  |", " -|-- "},//G
    {"|    |", "|    |", "|----|", "|    |", "|    |"}, //H
    {" ----- ", "   |   ", "   |   ", "   |   ", " ----- "},//I
    {" ---- ", "   |  ", "   |  ", "   |  ", "---   "}, //J
    {"|     ", "|  /  ", "| /   ", "| \\   ", "|  \\  "},//K
    {"      ", "|     ", "|     ", "|     ", "|____ "}, //L
    {" _    _ ", "| \\  / |", "|  \\/  |", "|      |", "|      |"},//M
    {" _      ", "| \\    |", "|  \\   |", "|   \\  |", "|    \\_|"}, //N
    {" ---- ", "|    |", "| oo |", "|    |", " ---- "},//O
    {" ---- ", "|    |", "|---- ", "|     ", "|     "}, //P
    {" ---- ", "|    |", "|    |", "|  \\ |", " ---\\ "},//Q
    {" ---- ", "|    |", "| --- ", "|  \\  ", "|   \\ "}, //R
    {" ____ ", "/     ", "\\____ ", "     \\", " ____/"},//S
    {"-------", "   |   ", "   |   ", "   |   ", "   |   "}, //T
    {"|    |", "|    |", "|    |", "|    |", " ---- "},//U
    {"\\       /", " \\     / ", "  \\   /  ", "   \\ /   ", "    V    "}, //V
    {"        ", "|      |", "|      |", "|  /\\  |", "|_/  \\_|"},//W
    {" \\   /", "  \\ / ", "   X  ", "  / \\ ", " /   \\"}, //X
    {" \\   /", "  \\ / ", "   Y  ", "   |  ", "   |  "},//Y
    {"_____ ", "    / ", "   /  ", "  /   ", " /____"}, //Z
    {"      ", "   |  ", " -- --", "   |  ", "      "},//+
    {"      ", "      ", "------", "      ", "      "},//-
    {" ---- ", "|  __|", "| |  |", "|  -- ", " ---- "},//@
    {"      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "______"},// _
    {"     /", "    / ", "   /  ", "  /   ", " /    "},// /
    {"  |  ", "  |  ", "  |  ", "  |  ", "  O  "}, //!
    {"        ", "   /   /", " -/---/-", "-/---/- ", "/   /   "}, //#
    {"____  ", "    \\ ", "    / ", "   |  ", "   O  "}, //?
    {"  |   ", "  |   ", "  |   ", "  |   ", "  |   "}, //|
    {" \\    ", "  \\   ", "   \\  ", "    \\ ", "     \\"}, /*\*/
    {" _   / ", "|_| /  ", "   / _ ", "  / |_|", " /     "}, //%
    {"  /\\  ", " /  \\ ", "      ", "      ", "      "}, //^
    {" __ ", "|   ", "|   ", "|   ", "|__ "}, //[
    {" __ ", "   |", "   |", "   |", " __|"},//]
    {"  _ ", " |_|", "    ", "  _ ", " |_|"}, //:
    {" _ ", "|_|", " _ ", "\\_\\", "/_/"}, //;
    {"  __", " /  ", "_|_ ", " |  ", " \\__"}, //{
    {"__  ", "  \\ ", " _|_", "  | ", "__/ "}, //}
    {"  _ ", " /  ", "|   ", "|   ", " \\_ "}, //(
    {" _  ", "  \\ ", "   |", "   |", " _/ "}, //)
    {"   ", "   ", "   ", " _ ", "|_|"}, //'.'
    {" _ ", "\\_\\", "/_/", "   ", "   "}, //'
    {" _   _ ", "\\_\\ \\_\\", "/_/ /_/", "       ", "       "}//"
};
```

**GetSS.hpp**

This is used to get the screen size

```
#if defined(__unix__)
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#endif

class ScreenSize
{
    private:
        int h, w;
    public:
        void getScreenSize(int& height, int& width)//No idea how it works got from Stackoverflow
        {
            #if defined(_WIN32)
            CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
            GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
            width = (int) (csbi.srWindow.Right-csbi.srWindow.Left + 1);
            height = (int) (csbi.srWindow.Bottom-csbi.srWindow.Top + 1);
            #else
            struct winsize w;
            ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
            width = (int)(w.ws_col);
            height = (int)(w.ws_row);
            #endif
        }
        void UpdateSize()
        { getScreenSize(h, w); }
        int getHeight()
        {
            UpdateSize();
            return h;
        }
        int getWidth()
        {
            UpdateSize();
            return w;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code readability

This code is very hard to read, since you have used almost no whitespace (like empty lines) to visually distinguish related code, and you have way too many comments. Ideally, code should be self-expanatory: by giving functions and variables proper names and by using the right organization, it should be mostly self-documenting. Comments should only be used to explain the remaining things that would still be unclear for another programmer reading your code.

## Use a curses library

As you'll have noticed, nicely formatting the output is hard to do in plain C++. There isn't even a standard function to clear the screen. The latter, and printing in color, is also not easy to do portably, although printing ANSI escape codes are supported by many terminals and are indeed the best way to go. If you are using them anyway, also use them to [clear the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660837/5481471); this is much more efficient than calling `system()`.

Instead of trying to do this from scratch, I strongly recommend you use a [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29). These provide a standard interface for writing full-screen text applications, and there are implementations for most major operating systems.

## Sorting cards

I see you are using [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in your code, but then I was surprised that when sorting cards on color, you didn't use [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You can provide a custom function to determine what to sort on. For example:

```
void Sort()
{
    std::sort(AllCards.begin(), AllCards.end(), [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) {
        return getColor(lhs) < getColor(rhs);
    });
}
```

Or with C++20's [ranges algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges) it becomes even simpler:

```
void Sort()
{
    std::ranges::sort(AllCards, {}, getColor);
}
```

## Avoid stringly types

Instead of having cards be represented by strings, create a `struct Card` that describes a card. For example:

```
struct Card {
    enum class Color {
        RED,
        YELLOW,
        BLUE,
        GREEN,
    } color;

    enum class Type {
        NUMBER,
        SKIP,
        REVERSE,
        DRAW,
        WILDCARD,
        WILDDRAW,
    } type;

    int value;
};
```

This avoids having to parse strings all the time.